# SSHFS not working without sudo inside my python file, and not showing any error details

Tags: python, linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshfs

I need to start a network disk inside my python script with SSHFS.
I have a CentOS 8 on my local network and i can reach it, login with ssh and stuff on my WSL.

```
def sshfs(ip, user, password, path_fonte, path_montado, timeout=30, bg_run=False):

    fname = tempfile.mktemp()
    fout = open(fname, 'w')

    ssh_cmd = "sshfs " + "-o " + "allow_other " + f"{user}@{ip}:{path_fonte} " + f"{path_montado}"
    print(ssh_cmd)
    child = pexpect.spawnu(ssh_cmd, timeout=timeout, encoding='utf-8')
    child.expect(['[pP]assword: '])
    child.sendline(password)
    child.logfile = fout
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    child.close()
    fout.close()


    fin = open(fname, 'r')
    stdout = fin.read()
    fin.close()

    if 0 != child.exitstatus:
        raise Exception(stdout)
    return stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sshfs(ip="192.168.122.131", user="root", password="root", path_fonte="/root", path_montado="/mnt/123"))
    print(pexpect.runu("ls -l " + "/mnt/123"))
```

The script above doesn't show any errors when running, but it also doesn't work. the "ls -l /mnt/123" doesn't return any files (total 0), and if i go there manually, there's no files inside the folder.
It is not linux permissions, since the "123" folder has 777 on chmod, nor an issue with my linux, since the command above (the ssh_cmd variable) works when running it from command line, so it isn't a issue on my WSL / CentOS, i guess?
Also, when running this way:

```
def sshfs(ip, user, password, path_fonte, path_montado, timeout=30, bg_run=False):

    fname = tempfile.mktemp()
    fout = open(fname, 'w')

    ssh_cmd = "sudo sshfs " + "-o " + "allow_other " + f"{user}@{ip}:{path_fonte} " + f"{path_montado}"
    print(ssh_cmd)
    child = pexpect.spawnu(ssh_cmd, timeout=timeout, encoding='utf-8')
    child.expect("[sudo]*")
    child.sendline("(user_password)")
    child.expect(['[pP]assword: '])
    child.sendline(password)
    child.logfile = fout
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    child.close()
    fout.close()


    fin = open(fname, 'r')
    stdout = fin.read()
    fin.close()

    if 0 != child.exitstatus:
        raise Exception(stdout)
    return stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sshfs(ip="192.168.122.131", user="root", password="root", path_fonte="/root", path_montado="/mnt/123"))
    print(pexpect.runu("ls -l " + "/mnt/123"))
```

When running this way, it works wonders, but i cant rely on sudo sadly, since there's no guarantee that i'll have sudo permissions on the cenario i'm working on :(

Any guess on what's going on? I spent hours on this issue to no avail.

Comment: I'd recommend picking a mount-point under your own `$HOME`, that will avoid any issues of that sort.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide a [mre] including debugging details such as logs and information on your WSL environment. For example, try the option ```-o sshfs_debug``` when spawning the ```sshfs```. You said you succeeded when running the ```ssh_cmd``` command manually. Compare logs for two cases. Also, you are using the ```-o allow_other``` mount option. It requires the root privilege. See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html).